# difference in Coffescript / Javascript typeof

Tags: javascript, object, coffeescript

I'm trying to parse a object recursively not knowing if the next element is a string or a next, nested object.
I was thinking of doing this by looking at the typeof of the value; it would be a string or a object. But something strange is happening...

This Coffescript code is behaving strange:

```
c = (strLog) ->
  console.log strLog
console.clear()
c '------------'


translateDoc= (doc) ->
    c 'in translatedoc'
    for key,value of doc
        c key
        c typeof(value)
    return null

doc =
    str1: 'content1'
    str2: 'content2'    
    obj1:
        str3: 'content 4'
        str4: 'content 3'      

for key,value of doc
    c key
    c typeof(value)     

translateDoc(doc)
```

this will give this output:

```
str1
str2
obj1
object
in translate doc
str1
string
str2
string
obj1
object
```

which puzzels me; I would have expexted the string's to be there the first time too... when I passed the CS code into coffeescript.org, I got of course the JS code. But if I run that in jsfiddle, I get the expected result twice!... I cannot see what the difference is...

1) why do I not get the "string"-log the first loop, and
2) why /do/ I get in the interpreted JS, but not in the CS interpreter of jsfiddle?

the origional CS code:
[CS code in fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pwiegers/f3j6avpf/)

the interpreted JS code: 
[JS code in fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pwiegers/yashcxde/)

Willing to learn, but stumped for the moment... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your CS has a tab

```
for key,value of doc
  c key
  c typeof(value)  # tab instead of leading space
```

which causes it to transpile into

```
for (key in doc) {
  value = doc[key];
  c(key);
}

c(typeof value);
```

Comment: wow.. thanks! I need to cut/paste sometimes to a editor that will show whitespace... I am beginning to see why people don't like the significant whitespace in Coffeescript... :-)

Comment: Spacing gets me all the time. It's a good idea to run your code through http://www.coffeelint.org/